# Apim configuration on bluemix

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

How should APIM on bluemix be configured, and in particular, how can the  maximal JSON size be set?  The limit is actually on the string and this exact limit is hit, so the default value is 8k. I need the maximal value for the string to be set to 2MB.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming (not so much to json either). Probably serverfault?

Comment: APIM is a cloud service offered  to create, host and manage APIs to be consumed.  Most of the configuration aspects are handled already.  If you can provide an example of what you are trying to do with APIM, it will help us answer the question.  If you are looking at getting started on using API Management on Bluemix, please read the blog  Getting started with the Bluemix API Management Service at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/06/getting-started-bluemix-api-management-service/